# Is there a way to unhide multiple sheets at the same time in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a number of sheets that I want to unhide quickly in Excel. Do you know if it is possible to unhide multiple sheets at the same time?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able to have macros in your workbook I would go for this option...

You need the first block of code found [here](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T002603_Unhiding_Multiple_Worksheets.html).
I just tested in Excel 2007 and it works.

Answer (score 2):

In 2007, go to the View tab and find the Custom Views button.  Unhide all the sheets in your workbook and add a custom view called "ShowAll".  Then hide the sheets you want and create another custom view called "HideSome".  Now you can quickly hide and show those multiple sheets by selecting a custom view.  Of course you'll want to name your custom views better than my example.

In 2003 and earlier, it's under the View menu.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. No. Microsoft doesn't feel that an Unhide All option would make for a less convoluted experience. In fact, just accept the fact that most questions around productivity improvements in Excel are answered with "No".